# Can't install py-subversion on freebsd 8.2

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to install python bindings for subversion:

```
# cd /usr/ports/devel/py-subversion
# make
===>  Patching for py26-subversion-1.6.15
===>  Applying extra patch /usr/ports/devel/py-subversion/../../devel/subversion/files /bindings-patch-subversion--bindings--swig--perl--native--Makefile.PL.in
cannot open /usr/ports/devel/py-subversion/../../devel/subversion/files/bindings-patch-subversion--bindings--swig--perl--native--Makefile.PL.in: No such file or directory
*** Error code 2
```

Yes, there is no such file in `subversion/files`, but there is file `patch-subversion::bindings::swig::perl::natives::Makefle.PL.in` (with colons instead of hyphens).
After renaming and rerunning `make` I got another error:

```
# make
===>  Patching for py26-subversion-1.6.15
===>  Applying extra patch /usr/ports/devel/py-subversion/../../devel/subversion/files/bindings-patch-subversion--bindings--swig--perl--native--Makefile.PL.in
cannot open /usr/ports/devel/py-subversion/../../devel/subversion/files/bindings-patch-subversion--bindings--swig--perl--native--Makefile.PL.in: No such file or directory
*** Error code 2
```

But now there is nothing like `bindings-*` in `subversion/files`.

So, the question is why is it so and how can I install py-subversion?

PS: FreeBSD is running on virtual private server, so I think it is somehow patched.

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD mskhug.ru 8.2-PRERELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-PRERELEASE #0 r50: Thu Feb 24 10:15:34 IRKT 2011 root@freebsd8-amd64.ispsystem.net:/root/src/sys/amd64/compile/DEBUG  amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things to try:

Erase entire ports tree

Get new up-to-date ports tree

```
# rm -rf /usr/ports
# portsnap fetch
# portsnap extract
```

Then try making the port again.